# Criar VirtualHost na porta 81

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost

Tenho dois apaches instalados para duas versões de PHP (5 e 7), na porta 80 e 81 respectivamente.

Gostaria de criar virtualhost para porta 81 do apache

No arquivo host tem essa linha:

***Host***

```
127.0.0.1        projeto.dev
127.0.0.1        localhost81
```

Criei um arquivo chamado projeto81.conf dentro de uma pasta chamada alias

***projeto81.conf***

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81> 
  DocumentRoot C:/www81/projeto/public
  ServerName projeto.dev
  <Directory "C:/www81/projeto/public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Dentro do arquivo httpd.conf adicionei a linha:

***httpd.conf***

```
# Alias

Include conf/alias/*.conf
```

Reiniciei o serviço, mas não funciona.

O que tenho que fazer a mais?

Para o `localhost81:81` funciona

A partir daí gostaria de disponibilizar esse vhost na rede local

Comment: Você está em ambiente linux? Usando algum xampp ou instalou apache e PHP nativamente?

Comment: PHP e Apache separados

Comment: Em ambiente WIndows

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso você usa os proxys, o apache continua recebendo as requisições na porta 80, e então ele encaminha para outro host e porta, portanto não precisa definir diretórios nesse tipo de vhost, o apache apenas re-encaminha a requisição.
ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost81
  ServerAlias localhost81
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

No arquivo hosts, você continua com o alias localhost81. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: lembrando que o mod_proxy deve estar habilitado no seu apache.

Comment: Esta configuração deu erro no meu apache

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: o apache não inicia

Comment: Consegue ver os logs? certificou-se de habilitar o mod_proxy no apache?

Comment: Acabei de habilitar o mod_proxy

Comment: Agora deu `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Será que tem algo a ver com o dns da rede local?

Comment: Se você está rodando tudo na sua máquina não pode ser dns local, você tem acesso aos logs do apache? Para termos informações mais precisas.

Answer (score 2):

Quando eu configuro outras portas no apache, eu costumo colocar a seguinte instrução junto com os VirtualHost:

```
Listen 81
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-81"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-8080"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Mas já tenho localhost da porta 80 e se quisesse acessar da porta 81 tipo localhost81 apenas trocaria o servername?

Comment: Eu coloquei **localhost** no exemplo porque eu aponto vários hosts para o localhost em pastas diferentes. Isso funciona se vc colocar no arquivos de hosts do Windows. No seu caso, acho que faltou vc indicar para o apache escutar a porta 81: **Listen 81**

Comment: Você pode colocar várias pastas para serem executadas na porta 80 do apache. 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host1
    DocumentRoot "/sua/pasta"
</VirtualHost>`

Você pode criar vários VirtualHost com o mesmo ServerName (localhost), e mudando somente a pasta. Daí vc acrescenta esta linha no arquivos de hosts do Windows (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc):
`127.0.0.1    host1
127.0.0.1    host2`

Comment: Mas isso não seria para multiplos hosts no mesmo server? Pelo que entendi, ele tem 2 apaches, com duas versões diferentes de PHP em cada um deles, assim sendo, acho que o melhor é que o apache da porta 80 aponte para o apache da porta 81 em determinado host, não?

Comment: Na verdade uma solução melhor e mais prática para ambiente de desenvolvimento (local), é utilizar docker, aí vc levanta um ambiente php 7 ou ambiente php 5, sempre que precisar, aqui tem alguns exemplos: https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/docker-environments

Answer (score 1):

Esta configuração e simples, primeiro passo e colocar o apache para escutar na porta que você desejá, o segundo passo e configurar o vhost para aponta a porta para um diretório que se deseja carregado quando solicitado, após isso e só da um reload ou restart o serviço.

## Primeiro passo

> Em alguns SO você irá encontrar esta opção em **httpd.conf**, se for no Debian você irá encontra em **/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

`Listen 81
Listen 80`

## Segundo passo

> Em alguns SO você irá encontrar esta opção em **httpd.conf**, se for no Debian você irá encontra em **/etc/apache2/sites-available/**, para habilitar no Debian e só rodar o comando **a2ensite [nome do arquivo de configuração]**.

`<VirtualHost *:81>
    #ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www_81
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www_80
</VirtualHost>`

Obs.: O **ServerName** esta comentado devido não ter necessidade de especificar um hostname, se você possuir um domínio valido e publico pode esta colocando.

`~# service apache2 reload`

ou

`~# service apache2 restart`

## Segue exemplo

Para facilitar segue um exemplo do caso informado, utilizando a mesma porta mudando só o endereço (host).

Host

`127.0.0.1        projeto.dev
127.0.0.1        localhost81`

Crie 2 arquivos dentro da pasta chamada alias, o qual foi criado por você.

projeto81.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot C:/www81/projeto/public
  ServerName localhost81
  <Directory "C:/www81/projeto/public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

projeto_dev.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot C:/www/projeto/public
  ServerName projeto.dev
  <Directory "C:/www/projeto/public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Dentro do arquivo httpd.conf permanece da forma o qual já foi configurado por você.

Acredito fica de uma forma adequada para o que você deseja e não precisa especificar a porta :), só irá mudar o host (endereço) digitado na URL do browser.

Att.

Comment: eu criei um no hosts no sistema operacional para testar eu usei localhost81

Comment: Se não for no mesmo SO (Sistema Operacional), você terá que adicionar em cada um o host localhost81 resolvendo para o IP da maquina que esta com o serviço apache rodando, e no apache você configura o **VirtualHost** atribuindo o **ServerName localhost81**, só que quando for acessar via browser terá que acessar da seguinte forma http://localhost81:81.

Eu costumo usar da seguinte forma, http://[IP]:80 ou http://[IP]:81, e atribuo a configuração apresentada aceima.

Comment: Por enquanto é no mesmo sistema operacional, mas eu queria deixar pronto para ser acessado da rede local lá no servidor

Comment: Interessante que só funciona para localhost81, se for adicionar outro vhost não funciona

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional do servidor, exemplo para o FreeBSD você configura direto no httpd.conf, já no Debian você criar um arquivo de configuração e depois você da um a2ensite [nome do arquivo].

Mais as configurações adicionadas neste arquivos costuma ser as mesmas, lembrando que após concluir as configurações você deve restartar o serviço apache.

Comment: Tentei colocar no comentário só que não deu :), editei a resposta colocando um exemplo para facilitar ;).

Answer (score 0):

Acho que só falta colocar a escuta no arquivo httpd.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:81
```

Para acesso mude a porta após os (2 pontos)

Ex:

```
http://localhost:81
http://localhost:82
```

Para funcionar em todas as máquinas da rede use o IP da máquina onde está configurado o apache.

Ex:

```
http://192.168.0.43:81
http://192.168.0.43:82
```